# mostrar alerta al querer actualizar la pagina javascript

Tags: php, javascript

estoy haciendo un script que al momento de actualizar la pagina me salga una alerta si quiere actualizar

tengo esto de codigo

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return 'estas seguro de refrescar la pagina';
};
```

el codigo no siempre muestra la alerta ademas cuando se actualiza actualiza la pag y se reinicia mi barra de progreso.lo que quiero que antes de actualizarse muestre un alert si quiere actualizar o no

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa con este evento es que no será lanzado hasta que el usuario realice alguna acción en la página como dar un **click** o usar el **scroll**.

En mi opción podrías dejarlo así, si el usuario no hizo nada, no hay datos que se puedan perder.